# How to Reduce geometry (faces) and still be faithful to geometry?

Tags: modeling, mesh, geometry

I made this Apple Watch dial, it is quite high poly for my computer with around 113000 faces.

I want to do a closeup shot of this as well as full shots of the watch, but I want to make it light weight. How do I do it without losing any detail?

Is there any professional secret to make semi-low poly hard surface model and still be able to do close up shots and look nice?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried a normal map, baked from the high-poly object? Then use it on a low-poly version?

Comment: @Blunder No, I have not. I don't know how to do it. Please tell more.